# Decodificar Base64

Tags: base64

alguien me podria ayudar a decodificar estos dos codigos? creo que deberia alguna  key, pero no logro entender como lo podria hacer, gracias.

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES-CTR,
KEYFORMAT="com.microsoft.playready",
KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1",
URI="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-16;base64,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"
```

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES-CTR,
KEYFORMAT="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed",
KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1",
URI="data:text/plain;base64,AAAAMnBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAABISENM346jIe0yKirfQndAx3H4="
```

Comment: https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: No decodifica, salen errores, no se si estoy haciendo las cosas mal, no soy bueno en esto, pero me sale letras erroneas, lo podrias comprobar tu mismo?

Comment: Por si acaso, base64 es lo que está luego de URI, entre de las comillas. Si lo que está codificado no es un archivo de texto, tiene sentido que veas símbolos raros.

Comment: windows/microsoft usa utf16 o unicode o una codepage, proba la opcion autodetect